# asp.net Custome Control and javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, custom-controls

I have master page with custom button control. I have one javascript function in master page. When i try to call this javascript function with in custom control code behind its not invoking. pls check below code.

Javascript code in master page

```
  function loader()
  {
  //Note: ctl00_loader is master page control.
  document.getElementById('ctl00_loader')="X"; 
  }
```

Mycustom control is

```
   <Shri:ConfirmBtn ID="UsrBtn" runat="server">
```

Code-behind code is

```
  Protected Sub UsrBtn_ConfirmClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles UsrBtn.ConfirmClick
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(String), "MyCode1", "<Script 
   Language=Javascript>loader();</script>")
 End sub
```

code behind line is working fine in page loading time. but when i place it custom control click (UsrBtn_ConfirmClick) inside its not loading. how to solve this one? any idea please.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

In the header of your html page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then capture the button click

```
$("#<%=UsrBtn.ClientID%>").bind("ConfirmClick", function () {
    // Do whatever you need here ....
});
```

To debug code embedded in the page add the keyword `debugger;` like so:

```
$("#<%=UsrBtn.ClientID%>").bind("ConfirmClick", function () {
    // Do whatever you need here ....
    debugger;
});
```

This will force the IDE to stop on that line then you can use the F10 key to step through the code like you would in the code behind.

Comment: No. My requirement is different one. I have custom control. i need to write code with in that custom control properties\events with code behind itself need to call javascript function. I wrote it. but not working.. I have referred this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350184/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind-c-sharp-in-a-user-control

Comment: I bound the javascript to the wrong even, `click` instead of `ConfirmClick`, whether it's a custom control or not it still should work.  You are doing exactly the same this with `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`, binding the javascript to the `ConfirmClick` event.

Comment: Hi Sir., Check my code i called ConfirmClick event only "Protected Sub UsrBtn_ConfirmClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles UsrBtn.ConfirmClick"   but i did get any error but javascript not loading or not invoking.. this is my problem.

Comment: Can you post all relevant code?  I seem to be missing something.  When does `ConfirmClick` get called?  When the `UsrBtn` button is clicked or some other event?